# Makefile variable value from command

Tags: shell, variables, makefile

I have a Docker container running and I would like to kill it using `make kill`.

Here's my *Makefile*:

```
kill:
    CONTAINER=$(docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=container-name); \
    docker kill $$CONTAINER
```

It gives error:

```
CONTAINER=; \
docker kill $CONTAINER
"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker kill --help'.
```

It seems that the variable `CONTAINER` is empty.
However running in the shell:

```
$(docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=container-name)
```

Returns the container id, in fact it prints:

```
c1cddc4d19a0: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have not defined a make variable named `docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=container-name`, and you instead want to run that as a program and obtain its output.

If so, you need to escape the `$` here like you did for the variable:

```
kill:
        CONTAINER=$$(docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=container-name); \
        docker kill $$CONTAINER
```

Otherwise make thinks that `$(docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=container-name)` is a reference to a non-existent variable and will substitute the empty string.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was struggling with this line `VERSION = $(git describe --tags --always || echo "unknown version")` and it turned out I only needed to append the missing `$` to the beginning (`VERSION = $$(git describe --tags --always || echo "unknown version"`)